# Styling Issue with flex box, text going too far

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have attached image below that shows that the flex box is going too far, I want to shift Hello in the grey row to be inline with the bottom Hello.

I tried applying a flex-wrap but it did not work and making the display inline-block

[image]
Code

```
<Pane display="flex" marginBottom={8}>
    <Pane display="flex" flexDirection="column" marginRight={16}>
        <Heading color={inProgressBar} size={900}>
           {XX}
        </Heading>
        <Heading flexWrap="wrap" size={100}>
           {Hello Hello Hello}
        </Heading>
    </Pane>
</Pane>
```

Comment: This issue could be caused by having a flex box directly inside another flexbox. Maybe try adding an additional div in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **position: absolute** to position the Hello wherever you want, by specifying the left and right values.

Answer (score 0):

Try `align-self: flex-end;` on the `Hello` element.